# mariabackup slave info and multi-master replication

Tags: backup, multi-master, mariadb-10.3

I have several master databases using mariadb 10.3 and replicate then all to one replica using [multi-master replication](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/multi-source-replication/). All is working fine.

I want to backup that replica server, so i can restore it quickly if needed, with all the multi replication setup.
In the past, I used mariabackup with --slave-info when i only had one master replication and the restore worked fine and i had the xtrabackup_slave_info with the required info to restore the replication.

Now with mutl-master replication, the `--slave-info` report that there is no replication setup and looks like it do not support the multi-master support.

So i'm missing something or mariabackup fail to support this? what other people do to backup a mariadb multi-master setup that allow easy replication restore?

Comment: I read about the same issue in percona xtrabackup (father of mariabackup) and I know that they fix this problem. I would suggest communicating with MariaDB support and/or try with percona xtrabackup.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/percona-xtrabackup/+bug/1705484

Comment: sadly percona xtrabackup do not support mariadb 10.3, that is why mariabackup must be used. In mysql, a multi-master `show slave status \G` show various rows, but in mariadb, it return empty and it requires `show all slave status \G'